# How to prove existence of directional derivates and discontinuity on same point?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> \begin{align} f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^3y}{x^6 +y^2} & \text{ if } (x,y) ≠ (0,0) \\ \\  0 & \text{ if } (x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}. \end{align}
>
> Prove that all directional derivates exist on $(0,0)$ and prove that $f$ is
> discontinuous on $(0,0).$

For the first part I used a generic vector $v=(v_1,v_2)$ and the definition I have of a directional derivate:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} (x_0,y_0)= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0 + hv_1, y_0 + hv_2) - f(x_0, y_0)}{h}
\end{align}

So I have:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} (0,0)&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{(hv_1)^3hv_2}{(hv_1)^6 +(hv_2)^2}- 0}{h} \\ \\
& = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{h^3v_1^3v_2}{h^6v_1^6+h^2v_2^2} \\ \\
& = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{hv_1^3v_2}{h^4v_1^6+v_2^2} \\ \\
& = 0
\end{align}

Since the limit exist for a generic vector it must be true all directional derivates exist. $(?_1)$

For the second part, since $(0,0)$ is a limit point of the domain, limit and continuity definitions are equivalent. So I looked for paths to get closer to $(0,0)$ that they gave me different results:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,x³) &= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x³x³}{x⁶+x⁶}=\frac{1}{2} \\ \\
\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,0) &= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x³(0)}{x⁶+(0)²}=0 \:(?_2)
\end{align}
Since the results are different it must be that $f$ is discontinuous on $(0,0)$.

So, I want to check if my reasoning was correct, and also clarify the two doubts I marked:

$(?_1)$ Is this statement correct?

$(?_2)$ I reason that the numerator is exactly 0, while the denominator is something that tends to zero. So, no matter how small the denominator is, the result must be 0. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance and my apologies if I formatted something wrong, first question here.

Comment: It seems nice to me. For point 2, remember that $f(x,0) = 0$ for every $x$, so this justifies your limit.

Comment: Looks fine to me. $(?_1)$ works since you used an arbitrary vector $(v_1,v_2)$. $(?_2)$ Yes. If the numerator is 0, your limit can't change it

Comment: It's correct, but you have a computational error (or typo?). The denominator in the last limit for the directional derivative is $h^4v_1^6+v_2^2$, not $h^3\cdots$.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, typo error. Corrected.